# php session issue either too many loops or doesn't work

Tags: php, session

Login script which I know needs some security which I will do once it works, I can log in until I add session info to top of admin pages then either shows login.php or get browser error too many redirect loops.

loginrequiredb.php is this file name

```
   <?php
   //calling connection to database
   include "connection.php";
   //start session
   //session_start();
   //if user posts for called login
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){
   //declaring variables for user input and using escape string to protect    php scripts
   $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$_POST['user']);
   $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$_POST['pass']);
   //select from users table where user input matches un and pw
   $sel_user = "SELECT * from users where un='$user' AND pw='$pass'";
   //put content held in sel_user into variable run_user
   $run_user = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sel_user);
  //use run_user counting rows and save in check_user
   $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
   //if content row numbers greater than 0 
     if($check_user>0)
     {
  //create session named username that is equal to content of $user
  $_SESSION['user']=$user;
  //display admin main page
     header('Location: ../adminmain.php');
   }
   else {
   //display log in error page
      header('Location: ../loginerror.php');
   }
   }
   //close database connection
   mysqli_close($dbconn);
   ?>
```

session for top of admin pages with lots of commenting out as tried more times than can count!
adminmain.php is this file name

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include 'includes/loginrequiredb.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])==' '){
    header("location: login.php");
    //}else {
    //session_destroy();
    //header("location: adminmain.php");
    //die();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's the name of this script? If it's adminmain.php you're redirecting back to itself infinitely.

Comment: my admin home page is called adminmain.php, login.php is form fill for log in.

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']=='')` and that space in `==' '` will fail you. Or `if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user']=='')`

Comment: There's a couple of problems here. Firstly there's a race condition between your redirects and your database connection closure, so sometimes the closure will be called and sometimes it won't. Move the connection close to before the `if/else` structure. Secondly, I'd be wary of the location-relative `Location` header. Make this domain relative (e.g. `/login/main.php` or whatever - i.e. prefixed with a `/`) or absolute (`protocol://domain.tld/login/main.php`).

Comment: Your indentation is rather uneven too - use tabs or four spaces and be strict with applying it consistently. Your outer `if` has no indentation, and the inner `if` starts the indent on the `if` line rather than its contents.

Comment: Your `session_start()` is commented out here, so this script absolutely won't work at present.

Comment: uncommented session start again can access log in page enter details just shown log in page again. However you can't get to the admin page directly so that works but sadly a user cannot log in either

Answer (score 2):

This statement will never work.

You're checking if 'user' exists in $_SESSION (true or false) == ' '. True or false will never == ' ' and therefore you will always redirect to your other script.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])==' '){
```

Change it to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
```

The general workflow should be something like this:

1. User hits login page
2. User submits credentials -> Posts to self
3. Login page detects credentials were entered and validates them
4. Valid credentials send the user to the "admin" script (and credentials need to be revalidated with every call)
5. Invalid credentials sends the user back to the login page.

Comment: this is what is was orginally but after hours of searching I came across another php tutorial laid out with the ==' ' why I tried it.  I have changed as advised still allows users to access admin page if uncomment else and second header then get too many redirects error in browser

Comment: tried print_r($_SESSION); shows array()

Comment: If your first script login.php and your 2nd script adminmain.php? Can you edit your post and add the filenames to each script for us?

Comment: file names added first script is loginrequiredb.php ys there is c,d,e,f,g so on as I have tried without any luck of succeeding :( and other 2nd script is adminmain.php just the session info above the html content of page

Comment: question now noted as duplicate :( I have looked at every possible question and answer tried millions different ways I wouldn't post if knew why it wont work